# Hiphop error when running program had compiled

Tags: php, compiler-construction, yii, runtime-error, hiphop

I have succeed when using Hiphop to try compile a simple yii app (generate with cmd `yiic webapp demo`).

`hphp test.php --keep-tempdir=1 --log=3 --include-path="../yii/framework"`

Compile-processing is not has any error or warning. I can start server with compiled-program with cmd:

`sudo /tmp/hphp_8AcATe/program -m server -p 8008 -v "Server.SourceRoot=`pwd`" \ -v "Server.DefaultDocument=index.php" -v "Server.EnableStaticContentFromDisk=true" -c $HPHP_HOME/bin/mime.hdf` 
(This cmd refer from [here](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop) - Example: Compiling WordPress)

After that, I access by browser via `http://127.0.0.1:8008` and then meet errors:

*UPDATE* (I have confusion in path below and fixed)

> HipHop Notice:  Tried to invoke /var/www/demo/../yii/framework/yii.php but file not found. in index.php on line 12
>
> HipHop Fatal error: Required file that does not exist: /var/www/demo/../yii/framework/yii.php in index.php on line 12

Here is line 12, index.php:

```
4.  $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
...
12. require_once($yii);
```

*UPDATE*

I've tried with realpath() as @prodigitalson's hint, but in console, program still output the same content :

> Required file that does not exist: /var/www/demo/yii/framework/yii.php in index.php on line 12

To avoid in relative path confusion case, I copied compiled program folder to `/var/www` (root dir with yii lib: `/var/www/yii/framework`), but nothing change :(

Have anybody meet this error the same to me? How to fix them? Thank for you help!

Comment: can you post line 12 of your index.php so we can see your require statment? It looks like the path is being resolved incorrectly.

Comment: @prodigitalson I have updated my question with code at line 12.

Comment: So does file `/var/www/demo/../yii/framework/yii.php` exist?

Comment: @zerkms Of course, I've worked with Yii for some time.

Comment: @Davuz: just to be sure check it with `cat /var/www/demo/../yii/framework/yii.php` in shell

Comment: @zerkms run `cat ...` ouput to screen content of yii.php. Is it ok?

Comment: @Davuz: dont use an unresolved relative path... wrap it in `realpath`: `$yii = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php');`

Comment: @prodigitalson I've tried with realpath(), but in console, `program` still output the same content : `Required file that does not exist: /var/www/demo/yii/framework/yii.php in index.php on line 12`

Comment: and what happens when you do an `ls -al /var/www/demo/yii/framework/yii.php`

Comment: Have you tried to access the file "/var/www/yii/framework/yii.php" directly? Does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

get rid of `'/..'` from `'/../yii/framework/yii.php'`